# parse csv file without ignoring first row

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a small parser for a csv file, where I read the number of coloumns from the first line.

However, I need the first line for calculations...is there a way to not ignore the first line?

```
with open(dataset_path, "r") as f:
    coloumns =  f.readline().strip().split(',')
    numRows = 0
    sums = coloumns
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(',')
            for i in xrange(len(values)):
                sums[i] = float(values[i])
```

Comment: Formatting? And how are you getting f?

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but I'll mention it just in case. Python comes with [a built-in module to parse and write csv files](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Comment: pls check the edited version

Comment: @Jon-Eric: sure. why not this method :-)

Comment: @user2015933 because there can be some subtleties involved with parsing csv files, escaping characters, line endings, etc, why not let a proven module `csv` do all the work for you?

Comment: Sure. i'll need to go thru the docs for that. since, i implemented this now. I'll save some time. i was just trying to work my way thru it

Answer (score 0):

If your file isn't huge, you can just read all the lines at once:

```
lines = f.readlines()
columns = lines[0].strip().split(',')
numRows = 0
sums = columns
for line in lines:
    values = line.split(',')
    for i in xrange(len(values)):
        sums[i] = float(values[i])
```

Comment: `sums = map(float, values)` or `sums = [float(v) for v in values]` both eliminate the loop.